# Decreased performance in ActiveMQ Artemis after paging

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis, messagebroker

After the broker switched to paging mode I am seeing a strange drop in performance. Some messages began to take a very long time:
1800мс
10мс
15мс
700мс

I am also seeing a lot of disk usage:

[image]

My `broker.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
         
      <thread-pool-max-size>50</thread-pool-max-size>
      <name>0.0.0.0</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

      <journal-buffer-timeout>16000</journal-buffer-timeout>

      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


      <acceptors>

         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP;useEpoll=true;</acceptor>

         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>

      </acceptors>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Linux Astra, 4 CPU 24GB ram 50GB SSD, ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7.0

only broker restart helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A decrease in performance *is expected* when paging. This is because messages are being paged to and from disk instead of being accessed directly from RAM. Even the fastest disks are much slower than RAM therefore paging reduces performance.

There are a few ways to mitigate this performance decrease:

- Provide the broker's JVM with enough heap space so that paging never occurs.
- Use [flow-control](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/flow-control.html) to prevent the excessive build-up of messages on the broker that leads to paging.
- Ensure that message consumption keeps up with message production to prevent the excessive build-up of messages on the broker that leads to paging (e.g. add more consumers, increase performance of existing consumers, etc.).
- Use high-speed [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)s instead of slower traditional [HDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)s.

My guess is that you're using mostly non-durable messages so that restarting the broker clears out these messages and eliminates the need to page thus restoring normal performance.

Also, since your using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7.0 I strongly recommend you upgrade to the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/). It's been over 2 years now since 2.7.0 was released and there have been many bug fixes and new features implemented in later versions.

Comment: thx for answer. I try to understand - why some messages are consumed quickly and some are slow (all have the same size) - some messages I could not receive for more than 30 seconds and crashed due to timeout of my webserver

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why it might take a long time to receive a message. It's impossible to say why exactly this is happening without more details about your use-case and the state of the broker when this happens. You might want to create a new question for this or possibly start a new thread on the [ActiveMQ users mailing list](http://activemq.apache.org/contact).

Comment: As for the crashing, that sounds like a rather serious bug in your application. It's always possible that a consumer might not receive a message so it should be prepared for that situation and handle it gracefully.